# Word-wrap around a specific character

Tags: css, html, xhtml, word-wrap

I have a string which looks like an absolute path : `Dir1\Important\Info 123\test`. I have that string in a `h:outputText` tag.

I want to word-wrap that string just before ot just after the `\` character. The default wrapping in css is for whitespaces. I can't use that because I have whitespaces in the some names. I want the string to break only at the `\` character.

How can I achive such word-wrapping? Any help is welcomed :)

PS: I can use `<wbr>` to give it a hint, but the problem with the whitespaces stays.

PSS: The tag looks like this:

```
<h:outputText id="fullPath"           value="#{configItemDtoSearch.fullPath}" 
                                      style="color:#03A9F4; font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap; width: 200;"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&nbsp;` instead of the white space characters. `&nbsp;` is a non breaking space character. So the string should look like:

```
Dir1\<wbr />Important\<wbr />Info&nbsp;123\<wbr />test
```

Comment: I replaced the normal whitespaces with the non-breaking one and added the <wbr />. When I use the `nowrap` property. The string doesn't break anywhere. When I omit the `white-space` property the string still breaks at the whitespaces (the replaced with non-breaking ones). Any ideas ?

Comment: Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2j4k3vk/2/) - please notice the white-space is set to "normal" (same as if it was omitted at all). Have you checked the HTML markup generated by the h:outputText tag? Is the final string in the HTML same as the one I posted above?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the CSS property to `no-wrap` and then add `<wbr />` tags after each `\` character then you should get the desired wrapping.

Here is an example - https://jsfiddle.net/f1t29gb4/. This works in Chrome but I've not tested it elsewhere.

Comment: I replaced the normal whitespaces with the non-breaking one and added the <wbr />. When I use the `nowrap` property. The string doesn't break anywhere. When I omit the `white-space` property the string still breaks at the whitespaces (the replaced with non-breaking ones). Any ideas ?

Comment: What browser are you seeing those results in?

Comment: In chrome, also in firefox.

Comment: Could you post a code sample on jsfiddle or similar? So I can see it running in browser.